# Terraform- Helm: Kubernetes cluster unreachable:exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" while deploy neo4jHelm

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, terraform, kubernetes-helm

i occure the problem while use terraform to deploy neo4j Helm chart. This raise the error like this:

```
Kubernetes cluster unreachable: exec plugin: invalid api version : "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1a1pha1
```

This is my terraform provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "1.10.1"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "2.11.0"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my neo4j config-Im using neo4j-4.1.3-1:

```
resource "helm_release" "neo4j" {
  name             = var.neo4j_release_name
  version          = var.neo4j_chart_version
  namespace        = var.neo4j_release_namespace
  chart            = "https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-helm/releases/download/4.1.3-1/neo4j-4.1.3-1.tgz"
  create_namespace = true

  values = [
    templatefile("./${path.module}/values/neo4j-values.yaml.tmpl", local.neo4j_vars)
  ]
}
```

My local kubectl 1.2.1, helm 3.0.3, Terraform v1.6.6. THis is my command run:
terraform plan -var-file=dev.values.tfvars -target=module.helm.helm_release.neo4j

Please help me!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i figure out how this work, because the API version v1a1pha1 is deprecated So instead using the default api, use this:
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
Change this in file ~/.kube/config